# Superscript in jfree chart

Tags: jfreechart

I have a x-y axis in jfree chart. In legend I want to use superscript(A/B^2) is there any solution for this?I found something for labels but how does it work for jfreechart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Unicode, e.g. A/B².

Addendum: For more [complex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7452088/230513) rendering, consider one of the [`org.jfree.chart.annotations`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/package-summary.html) suitable for imaging, such as `XYDrawableAnnotation`, `XYImageAnnotation`, `XYDataImageAnnotation`.

Comment: What if we want to have A/B^\u03C3 (sigma) or something? Is there a solution for that too?

Comment: @brimborium: I'd look at an [annotation](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/package-summary.html) that can handle an image.

Comment: @trashgod Ah, cool. That would be a possibility. Thanks for the link. :)