# Reduce Spaces in a GridLayout Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

Good day, please would like to know how to reduce the spaces between the labels and the Textboxes in this picture below and also how to create some spaces between the labels and the frame.Thank you.

[image: login page]

My code for this:

```
private void initUI(JFrame parent) {
    // private void initUI() {
   myPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,2,1,1));
   buttons_panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

   username_label = new JLabel("Username: ");
   password_label = new JLabel("Password: ");
   username = new JTextField(20);
   password = new JPasswordField(20);

   ok = new JButton("Ok");
   ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });

    cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           dispose();
        }
    });

    myPanel.add(username_label);
    myPanel.add(username);
    myPanel.add(password_label);
    myPanel.add(password);

    buttons_panel.add(ok);
    buttons_panel.add(cancel);

    getContentPane().add(myPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    getContentPane().add(buttons_panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    pack();
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
}
```

Should i be using GridBagLayout for this instead?..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All cells in `GridLayout` have equal size. You have to use [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) or [SpringLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html) or [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html).

Comment: Ok..Thanks. I was just wondering if it was possible on the GridLayout thats all.

Answer (score 3):

or use proper

1) [Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html)

2) set for Alignment (`left - right`, `top - bottom`) for

- used [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), simple example for [Boxlayout](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.swing/how-to-align-your-components-in-horizontal-or-vertical-l-2.html)
- [text alignment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingConstants.html) (`left - center - right`)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `GridLayout` `hgap` and `hgap` parameters and add a matching, empty `Border`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7452088/230513).