# In which components does GridLayout class setHgap() and setVgap() creates the gaps

Tags: java, swing, layout

I am using a grid-layout to set a group of around 256 Check-boxes on a JPanel. In the grid-layout documentation i can see that there are 2 methods i.e setHgap() and setVgap(). I am not sure between which components do these methods create gaps; would it be the adjacent checkboxes or the other components within the JPanel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setHgap() and setVgap() sets horizontal & vertical gaps respectively between components on the container itself and not along the 'edges'.

Comment: so in my case would it be the adjacent checkboxes?

Comment: yes, the gaps are internally between all checkboxes on the container.

Comment: Add an empty border to the enclosing container to complement the gaps, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7452088/230513).