# Is it possible to add a superscript to a superscript in a JLabel´s html?

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel

I need to show the function e<sup>Ax<sup>n</sup></sup> inside a JLabel, but trying to do so doesn't work  and only shows as e<sup>Axn</sup> which is confusing.  e<sup>Ax^n</sup> could help, but that's not what I'm looking for. 
Probably is because of the html version, or JLabels just dislike nested superscripts.

How else would you approach this for a JLabel?

Comment: I stumbled upon a discussion about this in the [java-forums](http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/55491-sup-tag-doesnt-work-properly.html). They recommend using JavaFX components to do this, but that's just too much for what I have to do, I'll stick to e<sup>Ax^n</sup>

Comment: See also this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7452088/230513).

Answer (score 1):

For that specific case there exists a special-2 `\u00b2`.

```
<html>e<sup>0.5x²</sup>
```

The HTML editor kit, and styled text uses character attributes, which probably prevent nesting of `<sup>` tags. Maybe with `<span style='...'>` something can be done too.

Comment: It's actually something more general like e<sup>Ax<sup>n</sup></sup>. I'll try the span tag. Thanks.
Also it's html inside a java's JLabel.

Comment: changing to a smaller font and to a vertical align with the span tag didn't work

Comment: Maybe ` <sub style='font-size: ...'>e</sub>0.5<sup>2</sup>`?