# Output fraction as numerator over denominator in java?

Tags: java, calculator

I am working on a scientific calculator in java for which I need to output a fraction in its actual form like as numerator over denominator.
Currently I am using JTextField to output my expressions.I know that this is not possible with JTextField, kindly guide me how this is possible ?

Comment: Perhaps use a label than

Comment: How exactly can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: You probably can use JLabel and set text to it in p/q form and show it.

Comment: possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448216/how-to-rendering-fraction-in-swing-jcomponents, several good answers there

Answer (score 1):

`new JLabel("<html>2 <sup>2</sup>&frasl;<sub>3</sub></html>")`