# jFreeChart : Customizing the linear chart axis labels

Tags: java, encoding, jfreechart

I'm using jFreechart to create a line chart like this (taken from demo) :

```
final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
            "Line Chart Demo 1",       // chart title
            "Type",                    // domain axis label
            "Value",                   // range axis label
            dataset,                   // data
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,  // orientation
            true,                      // include legend
            true,                      // tooltips
            false                      // urls
        );
```

Is it possible to convert the range and domain into the unicode encoding system ?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you be more specific about where on the chart you want the characters to appear?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6585876/230513) showing Unicode glyphs in the chart legend and in an annotation. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6659255/230513). See also [`org.jfree.chart.axis.SymbolAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/SymbolAxis.html).

[image]